# Download 1080p from iTunes store on Windows

Tags: itunes, windows, video

I am using iTunes 12.5.3.17 on Windows 10. iTunes Store pages show film/TV series Information sections which say "Downloading 720p". The title supports 1080p as well as 720p.

The text is a link to open the Store preferences tab. There is no setting to control quality on this tab. The Playback tab has preferred quality set to 1080p. The film downloads as 720p.

Multiple current pieces of documentation refer to this setting:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19623?locale=en_GB&viewlocale=en_US
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH20484?locale=en_GB

It is also mentioned that it is possible to download 1080p *even if your current device does not support it* (mine does, but compatibility problems should be ruled out by this statement).

Where has the setting gone? How can I download 1080p media?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is dictated by a setting in your iTunes preferences:

- Go to your iTunes Preferences
- Select the Downloads icon
- You will see a checkbox for *Download full-size HD videos*
- If you tick the above checkbox, this means iTunes will download movies and TV shows in 1080p when they're available

Exit your preferences.

Comment: Don't know whether I missed this tab or whether it temporarily vanished (I was being asked to authenticate a new machine, re-confirm payment details etc. - initial click on Rent failed to work). Either way, both the documentation and the link are for the wrong tab.